# How do I fix the error "Visio cannot provide fast search results"?

Tags: search, microsoft-visio

I have Visio 2010 installed. When I try to search for shapes I get the error:

> Visio cannot provide fast search
>   results because Windows Search is not
>   running or is not configured properly
>   for Visio.

Visio has all features installed. When I open up Windows Search Indexing Options there is no information about Visio.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should rebuild the indexed locations just in case something is messed up. Just delete and rebuild the index. Then manually add the following search location and try searching for shapes again:

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office 14\Visio Content
```

Comment: For Office 16, a little more obscured ... `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\Visio Content`